# Shankar's Active/Passive Change of Basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, unitarity

I'm working my way through Shankar's Quantum Mechanics (7th printing, and I'm doing it alone, so I apologize if I have core concepts completely wrong).

He has a section on Active and Passive Transformations (which seems to be slightly different from what I know as Active & Passive Transformations, but that would be a different question :) ), and it reads like this:

> Suppose we subject all the vectors $|V\rangle$ in a space to a unitary transformation
>   $$ |V\rangle \rightarrow U|V\rangle $$
>   Under this transformation, the matrix elements of any operator $\Omega$ are modified as follows:
>   $$ \langle V'|\Omega|V\rangle \rightarrow \langle UV'|\Omega|UV\rangle = \langle V'|U^\dagger\Omega U|V\rangle $$
>   It is clear that the same change would be effected if we left the vectors alone and subjected all operators to the change
>   $$ \Omega\rightarrow U^\dagger\Omega U$$

I was trying to wrap my head around this, so I was working through some examples I made up and realized that the formula $\Omega\rightarrow U^\dagger\Omega U$ only works when $U$ is unitary. In my own examples I worked it out for an arbitrary (viz. non-unitary) change of basis T to be $$\Omega\rightarrow T^{-1}\Omega T$$ Like I said, I worked this out myself, so it may be wrong, but it checks out for the unitary case because when $U$ is unitary, $U^{-1} = U^\dagger$.

My question is: *what part of Shankar's logic above makes use of the fact that U is unitary?* It seems like his logic holds fine even without that constraint, but then it gives us a formula that isn't true for non-unitary U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *definition* the matrix elements of an operator $\Omega$ are the expressions $\langle V|\Omega|V'\rangle$, and they transform as DanielSank described. However, their *interpretation* as actual coefficients of the matrix of $\Omega$ in the basis $V,V',\ldots$ only is correct when the $V,V',\ldots$ form an orthonormal basis. If $A$ is the matrix of $\Omega$ in any basis, and $T$ is the matrix mapping it to a different basis, the matrix of $\Omega$ in the new basis becomes $T^{-1}AT$.

In other words, the inner products $\langle TV|\Omega|TV'\rangle$, called matrix elements, are equal to $\langle V|T^\dagger\Omega T|V'\rangle$, but the elements of the matrix of $\Omega$ in the basis consisting of the columns of $T$ are equal to $\langle V|T^{-1}\Omega T|V'\rangle$, if the $V,V',\ldots$ form an orthonormal basis. These are equal only if the $TV, TV',\ldots$ still form an orthonormal basis, which is equivalent to $T$ being unitary.

Comment: Aha! So if I had a non-unitary transformation T, would the operator T^{\dagger}*Omega*T have any meaning? This makes me suspect that Shankar's "It is clear that the same change would be effected if we left the vectors alone and subjected all operators to the change..." is justified by the fact that all of the matrix's components would be the same? In that case, it would be relying on T's being unitary.

Comment: This question best captured my specific misunderstanding. I'd like to see a citation for the idea that the matrix elements of an operator are not the components of its matrix (I think it's more that those expressions aren't ecen the matrix elements of an operator unless V, V' are orthonormal. Otherwise, the expressions are almost meaningless), but I'm alright with the answer generally.

Comment: Rather than a citation I think it is useful to just work out an explicit example. You will already find relevant examples in the 2-dimensional real setting, e.g. taking an operator $\Omega$ that is $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ in the standard basis (corresponding to an observable with possible outcomes 0 and 1) and work out both the inner products $\langle V|\Omega|V'\rangle$ and the actual matrix in the alternative basis $V = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}, W = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: We have defined the notion of active and passive transformation for $\Omega$ here. What about $U$? Is that an active or passive transformation?

Answer (score 2):

If we rewrite the bra-ket expression in terms of matrix multiplication you can say

$$\langle V | \Omega | W \rangle \equiv V^{\dagger} \cdot \Omega \cdot W $$

where $\cdot$ means matrix multiplcation. Now suppose we transform $V$ and $W$ by a transformation $T$ (avoiding $U$ because I'm not saying anything about unitary-ness). Then we find

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle TV | \Omega | TW \rangle & \equiv & (T \cdot V)^{\dagger} \cdot \Omega \cdot (T \cdot W) \\
&=& V^{\dagger} \cdot T^{\dagger}\cdot \Omega \cdot T \cdot W \\
&=& V^{\dagger} \cdot (T^{\dagger}\cdot\Omega\cdot T )\cdot W \\
&\equiv& \langle V | T^{\dagger}\Omega T | W \rangle.
\end{eqnarray}

So actually, the daggers are the *general* case and it's only in the case where $T$ is unitary that you can write the transformation of $\Omega$ as $\Omega \rightarrow T^{-1}\Omega T$.

Comment: Where have you used the unitarity of T? An operator works well even if T is non-unitary, no?

Comment: @Prabhat I didn't, which is why it says in the answer *"avoiding $U$ because I'm not saying anything about unitary-ness"*. Read also the final sentence of the answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

The unitary condition for the transformation is not about the math here. A meaningful transformation for a quantum system must be unitary. Actually I think probably your derivation is right. You just need to assume this unitary condition.