# Diagonalization of inertia tensor

Tags: reference-frames, moment-of-inertia, linear-algebra

Imagine a part with an inertia matrix $I$. This matrix is symmetric and thus can be diagonalized. This means that a base $B$ exists where the $I$ matrix is diagonal (i.e $I=BDB^{-1}$), which is actually eigen vectors or $I$

This also means that a rotation matrix $R$ exists such that the part get its principal axes aligned with $x$, $y$ and $z$

Are $B$ and $R$ actually the same thing?

If yes, why?

If no, how can $R$ be found?

Comment: Yes. When we "diagonalize" a matrix, it is precisely the same thing as rotating our basis to line up with the eigenvectors.

Comment: However, this point can sometimes get obscured in linear algebra courses that portray matrices as blocks of numbers.

Comment: Ok, but rotating the inertia tensor is not the same as rotating the part and computing its inertia tensor, right?

Comment: No, that's exactly my point. "Rotating the inertia tensor" by taking $I \to RIR^{-1}$ is exactly the same as rotating your basis by $R$ and computing the components of $I$ in that new basis, which is the same as rotating your physical object by $R^{-1}$. (I might have dropped some inverses in there, though.)

Comment: OK, but why? Is it trivial?

Comment: It's covered in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/116856/shankars-active-passive-change-of-basis), you can also try most classical mechanics or linear algebra books.

Comment: It depends what you call "trivial", but it's essentially the *mathematical definition* of "how to transform a tensor from one coordinate system to another". Of course that raises another question, "why is the thing that we call an 'inertia tensor' the same as a mathematical tensor". Note, $B$ can be more general than $R$, since $\det R = 1$ by definition, but $\det B$ need not be $1$.

Comment: @knzhou,  we are guaranteed that an orthogonal matrix $B$ exists which will diagonalize $I$ , however for the matrix to be a proper rotation det$B$ should be +1. So how do we see that indeed $B$ is a proper rotation ? Could you please explain. Thank you :)

Comment: @Kashmiri If $B$ works but isn't proper, then $-B$ will also work, and it is proper.

Comment: @knzhou.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

To understand why, recall that the inertia matrix is the matrix of the linear function that maps the angular velocity vector to the angular momentum vector:

$$\vec{L} = I\,\vec{\omega}\tag{1}$$

Now rotate the co-ordinate basis, so that the components of $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{\omega}$ transform like $\vec{L}^\prime = R\,\vec{L}$ and $\vec{\omega}^\prime = R\,\vec{\omega}$. Now plug these equations (in the form $\vec{L} = R^{-1}\,\vec{L}^\prime$, $\vec{\omega} = R^{-1}\,\vec{\omega}^\prime$) into (1) to show that, in these co-ordinates, the inertia matrix must have elements given by:

$$I^\prime = R\,I\,R^{-1}\tag{2}$$

Next, we witness that $I$ is a symmetric, real matrix; therefore its eigenvalues are all real, therefore its eigenvectors are all real and:

**Exercise** Given that $I\,\vec{x}=\lambda_x\,\vec{x}$ and  $I\,\vec{y}=\lambda_y\,\vec{y}$ for two eigenvectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$, show that the symmetry of $I$ means that $\langle\vec{x},\,\vec{y}\rangle=\vec{x}^T\,\vec{y} = 0$ whenever $\lambda_x,\,\lambda_y$ are different.

**Exercise** Given the above result, show that an orthonormal transformation $R$ diagonalizes $I$. Therefore, we can find a co-ordinate rotation in (2) that indeed diagonalizes $I$.

---

You should be able to see that much of this reasoning applies to the matrix of *any* homogeneous, linear mapping between vectors, *i.e.* the transformation law (2) holds generally; there's nothing special about the inertia matrix. You need the matrix to be symmetric to show that you can *diagonalize* the matrix through a co-ordinate rotation, though.